# Error Error executing script RunApp: org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/mapping/filter/UrlMappingsFilter

Tags: grails, url-mapping

I am using grails 2.2.1.Whwn executing project i got the following error.

```
Error Error executing script RunApp: org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/mapping/filter/UrlMappingsFilter
```

UrlMappings.groovy

```
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
        "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
        }

        "/"(view:"/login/auth")        
        "500"(controller:'errors',action:'handleExceptions')        
        "404"(controller:'errors',action:'pageNotFoundException')        
    }    
}
```

Comment: Is there more of the exception?  Also, what is in UrlMapping.groovy?  It's impossible to answer this question as it stands

Comment: add `--stacktrace` to get more info (`grails run-app --stacktrace`)